# .NET Remoting and Server 2008 (64 Bit)

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a .NET application that is meant to be run on a local PC and started from a file share on the LAN.

It works fine on 32 bit Windows XP and Vista workstations.

But it fails with a System.InvalidOperationException on 64 bit Windows Server 2008.

It runs fine locally on all three configurations.

What could be the cause?

.NET 2.0 is installed an all machines involved.

Summary:

32 bit XP: runs locally and remotely
32 bit Vista: runs locally and remotely
64 bit 2008: runs locally, fails remotely

"remotely" means running locally but launched from a file share rather than a local drive.

Zone security is set to "full trust" for "Local Intranet" on all machines involved including the 64 bit 2008 machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the projects set to run in x86 mode?  Use the configuration Manager to check.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be Internet Explorer security settings.  Try adding your server as a Trusted Site.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Internet Explorer. Zone security is already set.

Comment: I understand your Zone security is set, but Windows Server and IE is more tightly integrated than we know.  Just try adding your server as  a Trusted site on the Win2k8 box.  I've had a similar issue with Win2k3, and the Trusted Site is the only setting that worked

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a security issue, I don't think the instruction set of the CPU makes a difference. I used to have the same problem when running applications from network drives.

I believe this should fix your problem.
[Caspol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Caspol and zone security settings make it work for 32 bit XP and Vista, but as I said it doesn't seem to affect Server 2008.